# What is the appropriate Way to Store Returned Sqlite Query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

What is the better way to store a returned query basing from the table creation below?+

> String CREATE_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + "(" + KEY_ID
>                     + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PRICE + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_ID + " TEXT," 
>                     + KEY_IMAGE_PATH + " NVARCHAR(1000)" +")";

The reason why I need the records from the `TABLE_ITEMS` because I need to display it in the GridView approach in displaying images using `KEY_IMAGE_PATH`. But my main problem is how can I store all the records from each columns, so that I can track what is the price and the image_path of each item displayed in the grid view?

```
public String[] getImagePath(){     
    List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT "+ KEY_IMAGE_PATH +" FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            paths.add(cursor.getString(0).toString());
            Log.d("getPathImage:", cursor.getString(0).toString());
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    db.close();
         //This should be returned as array string
     return paths.toArray(new String[paths.size()]);
}
```

It should be,

```
-itemid
-sellingPrice
-keyid
-imagePath[position]
-keyname
```

**LoadMainMenuActivty**

```
paths =  db.getImagePath();
intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, paths);
```

**ImageGridActivity**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

 //The images in only displayed but not the other details.
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                final ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    holder.br = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rBarHere);
                    holder.br.setIsIndicator(true);
                    holder.br.setFocusable(false);
                    holder.br.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                boolean fromUser) {
                            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Rating:"+rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }});
                    view.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
                }

                holder.text.setText("NAAA NA");
                holder.br.setStepSize(1);
                holder.br.setFocusable(false);

                Log.d("Image Path Value in GridView: ", imageUrls[position].toString());

                imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.image, options);

                return view;
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the returned `Cursor`? This has all info you need. I mean, why you need to store this in a separate data structure?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not sure how to use that, the image path should be contained as String[].

Comment: So I see you want to send the image paths through an `Intent`. For what? Is this `Intent` for another different app/process?

Comment: I added some codes above to help you. Thanks

Comment: Ok I see. Can you please post ImageGridActivity definition (public class ImageGridActivity...).

Answer (score 0):

The returned query should be a String array so I figured it out using the code below.

From the database handler I have to return `List<Menu> getItemsAsArray(String Table_Name)`, then

I have to put it in a loop to access the returned list and put it in a mashmap.

Then store it, `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ?>> values2`.

Then finally I have to access it through: `values2.get(position).get(TAG).toString()`